# Langchain's AttributeError: 'RunnableSequence' object has no attribute 'input_schema'

Tags: python, langchain

I'm trying to reproduce sequentially the code examples in the langchain documentation. Specifically, in the [expression_language/interface](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/interface) section, when running the line `chain.input_schema.schema()` it throws the error `AttributeError: 'RunnableSequence' object has no attribute 'input_schema'`.

In fact, when running `dir(chain)`, the property `input_schema` does not appear. The closest command seems to be `chain.schema()`. However, it returns a value different to the expected.

Note: the [documentation of the base class RunnableSerializable](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/schema.runnable/langchain.schema.runnable.base.RunnableSerializable.html#langchain.schema.runnable.base.RunnableSerializable) of the "chain" object, i.e., `langchain.schema.runnable.base.RunnableSequence` confirms that the property input_schema exists.

Full code (copied verbatim from the site):

```py
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

model = ChatOpenAI()
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template("tell me a joke about {topic}")
chain = prompt | model

# The input schema of the chain is the input schema of its first part, the prompt.
chain.input_schema.schema()
```

**What I tried:**

I ran `chain.schema()` with the following result:

```
{'title': 'RunnableSequence',
 'description': 'A sequence of runnables, where the output of each is the input of the next.',
 'type': 'object',
 'properties': {'first': {'title': 'First',
   'allOf': [{'type': 'array', 'items': [{}, {}]}]},
  'middle': {'title': 'Middle',
   'type': 'array',
   'items': {'allOf': [{'type': 'array', 'items': [{}, {}]}]}},
  'last': {'title': 'Last', 'allOf': [{'type': 'array', 'items': [{}, {}]}]}},
 'required': ['first', 'last']}
```

Expected result with `chain.input_schema.schema()`:

```
    {'title': 'PromptInput',
     'type': 'object',
     'properties': {'topic': {'title': 'Topic', 'type': 'string'}}}
```

Comment: Hi there! Please let me know if the below answer resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and I can confirm it works as expected on my machine. Note that these input/output schemas were [added last month](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/pull/11063/commits).

As you know, LangChain is ongoing many changes as more developers contribute to the project, which brings me to my next point.

### Outdated Package

You're most likely running an older version of LangChain. You'll need at least version `0.0.305` to call the `input_schema` property on your `chain`, `model`, or `prompt` objects.

### Upgrade to 0.0.321

Try upgrading to the latest version:

`pip install langchain==0.0.321`

Otherwise if you prefer not to use the latest version, make sure you're using at least version `0.0.305`:

`pip install langchain==0.0.305`

If you're using Jupyter Notebook you'll just need to make sure to restart the Kernel for the update to take effect.

---

Here are the tests from my machine (using Jupyter Notebook):

### Running version 0.0.304

[image: input_schema no attribute]

### Running version 0.0.305 (or above)

[image]

---

I'd love to know if this worked for you, otherwise we can try an alternate solution.