# RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain - NotImplementedError: Saving not supported for this chain type

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

I built a RAG pipeline and now want to save the model/pipeline locally. However when I try to save it I get an error message. Here is the code and the error output:

```
prompt_template = """ You are a chatbot having a conversation with a human. You can only answer in the German language.
Do not put English language or English translations into your answer.
{summaries}
Human: {question}
Chatbot:
"""

from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain

prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["summaries","question"],
            template=prompt_template)

chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": prompt}
#search_kwargs={'k': 7} -> The more the better, aber irgendwann ist Context Limit errreicht
rag_pipeline = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(
    llm=model, chain_type='stuff',
    retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(),
    chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs,
)

rag_pipeline.save("llama_rag_modell.json")
```

Results in:

```
NotImplementedError: Saving not supported for this chain type.
```

So how can I save my pipeline?

Comment: Hi, are you using the latest version? I am unable to replicate this issue on my machine. This seems to have been fixed here: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/pull/10132. There's also another thread related to the issue with a possible fix here: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/3983.

Comment: Hi, I used langchain 0.0.240 but saw there is a new version 0.0.326, so I will try this out asap!

Comment: Yup. Let me know if this ends up working for you and I'll draft a complete answer with more instructions for others that run into a similar problem. If not, please provide additional details or steps to replicate so I can better assist you.

Comment: worked for me! @jeff

Comment: That’s great, appreciate confirming the answer below because others will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OP mentioned in the comments above, the problem was an outdated version of `LangChain` specifically version 0.0.240.

The issue was fixed in more recent versions, here: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/pull/10132 and here https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/3983.

#### The solution in this case was to upgrade LangChain:

`pip install langchain==0.0.327`

Since `LangChain` and similar LLM frameworks are fairly new and getting major updates really fast, I advise anyone facing similar issues to check the [GitHub repo of the framework](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain), or the official [Python package site](https://pypi.org/project/langchain/) to determine why some methods may not work as provided in the official docs.

---

Here's another answer that is related to an outdated version of LangChain: [Langchain's AttributeError: 'RunnableSequence' object has no attribute 'input_schema'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77347999/langchains-attributeerror-runnablesequence-object-has-no-attribute-input-sc/77349162#77349162)

In this **one week old** post, the version went up `from 0.0.321` to `0.0.327`, so you know what I mean when I say things are moving fast!